# Creating a new UiBinder taking too much time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, gxt

I am facing a problem while creating a new UiBinder file in my project. It is taking too much time to create one and sometimes it doesn't create at all. The creation window stays as is. In some cases, when I close my eclipse and restart, the files are shown created. Can somebody help?

I am using Eclipse Juno. Working on GXT 3. JDK 1.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Juno has some problems related to the new interface code that was introduced into the Juno release. This implementation does for example have some problems related to redrawing opened editors over and over. You might solve some of these problems by updating to the latest version. There are even some hotfixes available to fix some of these problems. For now I recommend that you downgrade to Indigo.

Kepler will be released in June ( http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release ), and I really hope some of these problems will be fixed by then.